# Get variable without executing IronPython script

Tags: ironpython

Is there a way to retrieve a global variable defined by the script writer without actually executing the script? e.g only Compile the code

Comment: no, since something has to interpret the script. any values of global variables ain't stored anywhere beside your script. or write a script that reads your script without executing it

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I need to read an input from the user before actually executing the script, this means I must ask the users to create an additional script only for a single definition, kind of clumsy work. I really wanted to avoid plugging into IronPython source code but I guess this is where I have to go now. Anyway my plan is to add a variable at runtime that restricts any execution if it is in read only mode :)

say i want my users to define a const string then I cannot retrieve it ( hope you understand my pain )

Comment: write another script that you execute where the global variable is set into a config file (config.py e.g.) and then import it from your real script with `from config import *` reading this before executing shouldn't be a problem. you only have in your config.py variables stored like `myglobal = 'test'`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you essentially want to execute just some initial parts of script before executing something upon that. What I would do is the following, given that I operate on a scope variable instead of "global" variable.

```
    [Test]
    public void TestPythonDymanicCall()
    {
        string customScript = @"
            scriptScopeVar1 = 3
            def executeSomething():
                global scriptScopeVar1
                scriptScopeVar1 = scriptScopeVar1 + 1
        ".unindent();
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        engine.Execute(customScript, scope);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, engine.Execute("scriptScopeVar1", scope));
        engine.Execute("executeSomething()", scope);
        Assert.AreEqual(4, engine.Execute("scriptScopeVar1", scope));
    }
```